# Xamarin.forms cross platform Datepicker

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, cross-platform

I'am using Datepicker, and i want to customize the design in UWP project like the Android Project.
from design like this : UWP design
to design like this :Android design

Comment: Its their native designs you cannot change that

Comment: We can't customize the design?

Comment: No there could be available native alternatives but that's it

Comment: Any updates about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is that you could use the [CalendarView control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendarview?view=winrt-22000) as a data picker. You could put the `CalendarView` inside a `Popup` and add Buttons or TextBlocks to display data as you want.

A simple sample looks like this:

**Xaml**

```
<Popup x:Name="CalendarPicker">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Title"/>
            <CalendarView x:Name="CalendarView" SelectedDatesChanged="CalendarView_SelectedDatesChanged" />
            <Button x:Name="ConfirmButton" Content="Click" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Popup>
```

**Code-behind**

```
 public DateTimeOffset selectedData { get; set; }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(selectedData);
    }

    private void CalendarView_SelectedDatesChanged(CalendarView sender, CalendarViewSelectedDatesChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        selectedData= args.AddedDates.First();
    }
```